# Count elements in an array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, counting

I have an array that contains string elements:

```
farm = np.array(garden)
```

leads to this:

```
[['F' 'F' 'W' 'W']
 ['F' '_' '_' 'W']
 ['G' '_' '_' 'J']
 ['G' 'G' 'J' 'J']]
```

I want to count how many times lets say 'F' appears, is there a simple way to do this? This is a small version of the bigger array that I will be working on

Comment: Is this indeed a numpy array or a Python nested list of lists? Please format it to make it syntactically valid. And a hint: function `collections.Counter()` returns a dictionary of unique elements and their counts in a list.

Comment: Also, how many dimensions in your array? Is it 2 dimensions or 3?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
Lists have a count method. So your new and improved pythonic code is

```
D= sum([i.count("F") for i in listX])
```

Well you can make a function, that 
Checks if the parameter passed to it is in the array. You can even use list comprehensions. For example

```
F = sum([sum([1 for i in j if i=="f"]) for j in listX])
```

Comment: Of course the more readable solution is to make a function; Also im not sure if there is a count method for lists

Answer (score 1):

Michael's solution is the most "pythonic", but I wanted to offer an alternative solution using simpler constructs, in case you're just learning:

```
lst = []
lst.append(['F', 'F', 'W', 'W'])
lst.append(['F', '_', '_', 'W'])
lst.append(['G', '_', '_', 'J'])
lst.append(['G', 'G', 'J', 'J'])

numFs = 0
# Look at each sublist
for sublist in lst:
  # Look at each element within the sublist
  for s in sublist:
    # If the element is an 'F', add 1 to the number of Fs
    if s == 'F':
      numFs += 1
print(numFs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to reduce and join the elements of the arrays into a string and then count, like so:

```
from functools import reduce
a = [['F' 'F' 'W' 'W'], ['F' '_' '_' 'W'], ['G' '_' '_' 'J'], ['G' 'G' 'J' 'J']]
c = ''.join(reduce(list.__add__, a)).count('F')
print(c)
```

When executed, this code prints:

```
3
```